# FutureTask caused only 1 thread to execute in 4 threads pool?

Tags: java

Recently I am trying to use futuretask, I found the following issue

For example, if I have a task implements Callable

```
class Task implements Callable { 
...
}

Task task = new Task();
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    exec.submit(task);
}
```

I will have 4 threads to execute

If changed to FutureTask like

```
class Task implements Callable { 
    ...
    }

 class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask {
     ...
 }

    Task task = new Task();
    MyFutureTask ftask = new MyFutureTask(task);
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        exec.submit(ftask);
    }
```

I found only 1 thread gets executed.

Anyone knows why?